Why isn't my SwiftUI navigation stack / searchable loading when switching tabs?
I have an iOS app with different tabs, each tab has it's own view with embedded nested views as normal.
On one tab I have a .searchable() modifier and a NavigationStack, but I am getting this unresponsive / lagging behaviour when moving to this tab for the first time:
Nav Stack lag
This Views code is:

struct SearchView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var env: Env

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                SearchSelectorView()
                    .padding(.vertical, 5)

                if env.searchType == .report {
                    HStack {
                        DatePicker("Start:", selection: $env.report.from, in: ...Date.today().previous(.friday), displayedComponents: [.date])
                            .datePickerStyle(.automatic)
                        Spacer()
                        DatePicker("End:", selection: $env.report.to, in: ...Date.today().previous(.friday), displayedComponents: [.date])
                            .datePickerStyle(.automatic)
                    }
                    .padding(.horizontal)
                }

                SearchResultsView()
            }
            .searchable(text: $env.search, prompt: "Companies, Contacts, Projects")
            .navigationTitle("Search")
            .toolbar {
                Menu {
                    Menu {
                        Picker("Status", selection: $env.status) {
                            ForEach(env.project.projectStatuses, id: \.self) { result in
                                Text(result)
                                    .tag(result)
                            }
                        }
                    } label: {
                        Label("Status", systemImage: "calendar.day.timeline.left")
                    }

                    Menu {
                        Picker("Region", selection: $env.region) {
                            ForEach(env.report.regions, id: \.self) { result in
                                Text(result.name)
                                    .tag(result.name)
                            }
                        }
                    } label: {
                        Label("Region", systemImage: "location")
                    }

                    Button(action: {
                        env.region = "All"
                        env.status = "All"
                    }) {
                        Label("Reset", systemImage: "arrow.circlepath")
                            .tint(.red)
                    }
                } label: {
                    Label("Filter", systemImage: "line.3.horizontal.decrease")
                }
            }
            .onChange(of: env.searchType) { [weak env] oldValue, newValue in
                if oldValue == .company {
                    env?.companiesReset()
                } else if oldValue == .contact {
                    env?.contactsReset()
                } else if oldValue == .project {
                    env?.projectsReset()
                }
                env?.search = ""
            }
            .onChange(of: env.status) { [weak env] _, _ in
                env?.search()
            }
            .onChange(of: env.region) { [weak env] _, _ in
                env?.search()
            }
            .onChange(of: env.search) { [weak env] _, _ in
                env?.search()
            }
            .onChange(of: env.report.from) { [weak env] _, _ in
                Task { await env?.reports() }
            }
            .onChange(of: env.report.to) { [weak env] _, _ in
                Task { await env?.reports() }
            }
            .onSubmit(of: .search) {
                env.search()
            }
        }
    }

    private func search() {
        Task {
            switch env.searchType {
            case .project:
                if env.search.count > 3 {
                    await env.searchProjects()
                }
            case .contact:
                if env.search.count > 3 {
                    await env.searchContact(category: "0")
                }
            case .company:
                if env.search.count > 3 {
                    await env.searchCompany(category: "0")
                }
            case .report:
                await env.filterReports()
            }
        }
    }
}


I am sure there are a lot of imperfections in this code, any guidance would be appreciated
